# Why can't Service find my Repository bean?

Tags: spring-boot, service, repository, javabeans

I'm making a simple spring boot application and my service doesn't seem to notice my repository bean for some reason. I checked my configuration and it seems fine, I also basically just copied way that the repository is injected from a tutorial so i really don't even have an idea where might the problem be.

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Trucks, Integer> 
{

@Query("....")
List<Trucks> getTrucks();
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {


private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

@Autowired
public ProjectServiceImpl(ProjectRepository projectRepository) {
    this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
}

@Override
public List<Trucks> getTrucks() {
    return projectRepository.getTrucks();
}
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.javar.domain"
})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistanceContext {

private static final String[] ENTITY_PACKAGES = {
        "com.javar.domain"
};
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_DRIVER_CLASS 
="spring.datasource.driver-class-name";
private String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_URL="app.datasource.url";
private String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USER="app.datasource.username";
private String PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD="app.datasource.password";
private String 
PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT="spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect";
private String 
PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO="spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto";
private String 
PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY="spring.jpa.hibernate.naming- 
strategy";
private String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL="spring.jpa.show-sql";
private String 

PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL=
"spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql";

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();

dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty
(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_DRIVER_CLASS));
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredPropert
(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_URL));
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty
(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_USER));
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty
(PROPERTY_NAME_DB_PASSWORD));

    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource 
dataSource, Environment env) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new 
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITY_PACKAGES);

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    //Configures the used database dialect. This allows Hibernate to create SQL
    //that is optimized for the used database.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));

    //Specifies the action that is invoked to the database when the Hibernate
    //SessionFactory is created or closed.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));

    //Configures the naming strategy that is used when Hibernate creates
    //new database objects and schema elements
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate writes all SQL
    //statements to the console.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

    //If the value of this property is true, Hibernate will use prettyprint
    //when it writes SQL to the console.
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zavrsni?useSSL=false
app.datasource.username=....
app.datasource.password=....

#Hibernate Configuration
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = 
org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

And the error report:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.javar.serviceImpl.ProjectServiceImpl 
required a bean of type 'com.javar.repositoryy.ProjectRepository' that 
could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.javar.repositoryy.ProjectRepository' 
in your configuration.
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRepository;
```

and remove this contructor with that annotation:

```
@Autowired
public ProjectServiceImpl(ProjectRepository projectRepository) {
    this.projectRepository = projectRepository;
}
```

If this helps you or you have some questions, let me edit this answer later.

**UPDATED**

Make sure that the package is correct where repository is found.

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.javar.domain"})
```

So update the package to "com.javar.repositories"

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed unfortunately. Thanks for the help anyway. :)

Comment: @aratata what erro messages do you revieve?

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field projectRepository in com.javar.serviceImpl.ProjectServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.javar.repositoryy.ProjectRepository' that could not be found.


Action:


Consider defining a bean of type 'com.javar.repositoryy.ProjectRepository' in your configuration.

Still the same one

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally, so i just needed to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages =  "com.javar.repositoryy") above my Application class. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this error by adding (missing in my case) maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```